# Database connection issue with long time running shell in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have following database configuration in database.php file from my CakePHP app:

```
    public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => 'database',
            'prefix' => '',
    );
```

All is working fine, except of one queue shell script. The script is looping and waiting for commands to run (for example to update some reports). After a while 1-2 days database data is changing, but the script will still "see" the old data, and results of command is wrong. If I restart shell script, the results are OK... for few days.

I have to mention that I had "lost database connection" issue before in the script and I have solved it by runing every 10-15 min:

```
 $user = $this->User->find('first');
```

Now I am affraid this is making the connection persistent somehow...

How can I reset the database connection ?

EDIT:
I was just refactoring the code to check if I can set $cacheQueries to false on the Model. But in few parts of the code I am using ConnectionManager directly, and only then I have "cache" problem. If I query database from Model->find results are ok. I need direct queries for performance reasons in few places...

```
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(1) as result
            FROM 
            ......
            ";

$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Comment: I am wandering if I should run ConnectionManager::drop('default'); before the script runs... will it reset the connection?

Comment: Debug this script properbly. Send yourself an email after finishing the command, which I guess, your are executing via a cronjob?
Then you will see if the command run through at all.
Also you can log the steps you are taking in a log file and analyse it afterwards to find the stuff that did not work as expected.

Comment: It's not like that. Script is constantly on. looping in while loop, and checking rabbitMQ queue if there is a task to do. I can see in log the task is executed and compleated correctly. But results of query are from the past, like the database would freeze in the moment the script was run in the first place. If i restart the (looping) script and run the same task one more time: results are bac to "present"... Question is why looping script can only see database state from moment of it's execution, and will not see new updates ?

Comment: Which version of cakephp are you using? Did you try the solution of @burzum ? It sounds pretty much like a caching issue.

Comment: I am using CakePHP v2.4.2

Comment: Okay, then my answer applies to you. :)
Did it work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property $cacheQueries which @burzum mentioned, seems not to be in use in any cake model method.

But I found another interesting fact in the source of the [DboSource](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-DboSource.html#604).

You need to use the second parameter of the DboSource::query() method to turn off the caching. Or the third if you want to provide additional parameters for the DboSource::fetchAll() method.

Eventhough this will fix your problem, you should write your queries with the Model::find() method that CakePHP offers.

You should only not use them if they are seriously impacting your performance.

func0der

Comment: Query works, and I have confirmed it is fetched with $cache = FALSE param. In a few days I will know for shure if my script is working as expected (no cache).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set these two model properties to false:

- $cacheQuery http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Model.html#265
- $cacheSources http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Model.html#499

Comment: It turns out the problem was only when i Query directly with ConnectionManager...

Comment: Err... why do you run plain SQL queries directly through the DS at all?

Comment: it seem'd simpler and easy'er to use SQL query (I can test it directly on DB) than complex array of conditions for model...

Comment: If you do not want to use those arrays, you should properbly use something different than CakePHP, because this is one of the main efforts of it.
Also you could use the log feature of CakePHP to get the resulting queries which you can then test in your database, find the errors and change the "compley arrays" - they are actually very easy to use and self explaining as well - to your needs.